# want to write a query to find a tax in oracle.i had written it but it's not working plss check it and help me out

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g, oracle9i, plsqldeveloper

i had written a code to find the tax but its now working for the income above 10 lac plss help me out`enter code here

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION tax_func (p_sal IN NUMBER)
   RETURN NUMBER
IS
   tax      NUMBER := 0;
   v_tsal   NUMBER := 0;
   v_sal    NUMBER;
BEGIN
   v_sal := p_sal * 12;
   IF v_sal > 1000000
   THEN
      v_tsal := v_sal - 1000000;
      tax := (v_sal * 0.3);
      v_sal := v_sal - v_tsal;
   END IF;
   IF v_sal > 500000
   THEN
      v_tsal := v_sal - 500000;
      tax := (v_sal * 0.2);
      v_sal := v_sal - v_tsal;
   END IF;
   IF v_sal > 200000
   THEN
      v_tsal := v_sal - 200000;
      tax := tax + (v_sal * 0.1);
   END IF;
   RETURN tax;
END;
/
```

Comment: It would help to define "not working".  What do you  expect the output to be?  What output are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you want a single `IF` statement rather than three separate `IF` statements.  As it stands, if `v_sal` is greater than 1 million, all three `IF` statements will evaluate to `TRUE` so the end result will always be that the final `IF` statement ultimately computes the tax.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION tax_func (p_sal IN NUMBER)
   RETURN NUMBER
IS
   tax      NUMBER := 0;
   v_tsal   NUMBER := 0;
   v_sal    NUMBER;
BEGIN
   v_sal := p_sal * 12;
   IF v_sal > 1000000
   THEN
      v_tsal := v_sal - 1000000;
      tax := (v_sal * 0.3);
      v_sal := v_sal - v_tsal;
   ELSIF v_sal > 500000
   THEN
      v_tsal := v_sal - 500000;
      tax := (v_sal * 0.2);
      v_sal := v_sal - v_tsal;
   ELSIF v_sal > 200000
   THEN
      v_tsal := v_sal - 200000;
      tax := tax + (v_sal * 0.1);
   END IF;
   RETURN tax;
END;
/
```